# Matrix Multiplication in Python Language

Tags: python, matrix

I'm trying to do a Matrix multiplication using nested while loops for the given hard coded matrices...

The correct answer for this should be [[6,12], [15,30], [24,48]]

but the output of my code is [[6,12], [6,12], [6,12]]

what should I do?

```
a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b=[[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]]
c=[]

cola=len(a)
rowa=len(a[0])
colb=len(b)
rowb=len(b[0])
r,s,t,u,sum = 0,0,0,0,0

c=[([0]*rowb)]*cola

print c


while s<cola:
    while u<rowb:  
        while t<colb:
            d=a[s][t]*b[t][r]
            sum+=d
            t+=1

        c[s][r]=sum
        sum=0
        u+=1
        t=0
        r+=1

    r=0    
    s+=1

print c
```

Comment: Any reason why you can't use `numpy`?

Comment: As much as possible, we are being refrained from importing modules to be able to practice the basics more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

matrixA = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
matrixB = [[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]]
result = []

for row in range(len(matrixA)):
    rowResult = []
    for column in range(len(matrixB[0])):
        s = 0
        l = len(matrixA[row])
        for i in range(l):
            s += matrixA[row][i]*matrixB[i][column]
        rowResult.append(s)
    result.append(rowResult)

print result
```

I try this, it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

When you do -

```
c=[([0]*rowb)]*cola
```

You are just copying the inner list `cola` times, this is shallow copying, hence each inner list is a reference to the same object , hence when you change an element inside one of the inner lists, it affects all of the inner lists. Instead of that, try using list comprehension to create the `c` list.

Example -

```
c = [[0 for _ in range(rowb)] for _ in range(cola)]
```

Also, another small issue in your logic, you are using `r` to denote the elements from `b` , but in the while loop you are checking against - `u` , you should check against `r` . Example -

```
while s<cola:
    while r<rowb:
```

Comment: Why did it copy the first one to all not the last?

Comment: There was a small issue in the logic as well, it was only calculating for first row, I have added the issue description and possible fix for that in the answer as well. Thanks

Comment: Please check the latest answer, there is a small mistake in the logic, which I have pointed out in the answer.

Comment: I would like to advice that if the answer was helpful for you, please do accept it (by clicking on the tick mark on the left side so that it becomes green) . It would be helpful for the community.